# Update SQL attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column in a Oracle table so that the `Goals` column for each `Game` receive average  goal scored from the `goal_scored` in the Player table but I keep getting the following error message:

> "Error: ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"

I have tested the query and it returns 10 rows as much as the `Games` are as well as the right result.

This is my code:

```
UPDATE GEN
    SET Goals = (Select AVG(goal_scored) FROM Player, Gen, Game
    WHERE Game.Name=Gen.Gameid AND Player.Gameid=Game.Name
    GROUP BY Player.Gamename);
```

If I skip the `GROUP BY` I don't get the error but all `Game`s get the same average score.

Comment: I see a kind of cross join in your nested query, here: `FROM Player, Gen, Game`

Comment: The subquery after `SET Goals =` has to return just one row with one value. Your question doesn't explain how to calculate the average - is it by player? If not, what? And can you show your table structures?

Comment: You do not need a Group By in queries where you select a single aggr. value. Aggr. functions return a single value, not multiple values. The result of your select will be a single row-nothing to group. If not then it is a wrong query.

Comment: @ITBeginner Please, do not edit questions randomly: "Oracle" and "returns 10 rows" are not valid candidates to format as code. If you edit the post, note the tags, the key words and what is asked/answered before submitting your edit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip `Gen` in the subselect (but keep it in the `where` clause):

```
UPDATE GEN
    SET Goals = (Select AVG(goal_scored) FROM Player, Game
    WHERE Game.Name=Gen.Gameid AND Player.Gameid=Game.Name);
```

This solves your syntax error, but I have a feeling that it's not what you want.
See question comment by Ed Gibbs.